# How to display contant and value of variable together using applescript

Tags: excel, macos, automation, applescript

how can i display constant and value of variable together using applescript.

example

set test to 2

display dialog ("A"+test)

when ever i run this i get a error message "Can't make "A" into type number".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To concatenate strings together use "&", not "+". Notice we can concatenate strings, so a number should be coerced to a string before concatenating them.

```
display dialog ("A" & (test as text))
```

Comment: Note that you don't actually need to cast the right-hand operand as the concatenation (`&`) operator will automatically do that for you, so `("A" & test)` is sufficient here. The `&` operator decides which type of value to return according to the type of its left operand. If it's `text`, the right operand is coerced to text and the result is text; if it's `record` the result is a record; if it's any other type, both operands are coerced to lists before being joined, and the result is a list. e.g. `("A" & "B") = "AB"`, `("A" & 3) = "A3"`, `(3 & "A") = {3, "A"}`, `((3 as text) & "A") = "A3"`

Comment: Yes, I know however I'm trying to teach someone how to add strings together. Since it's apparent he knows very little about applescript there's no reason to go into the nuances of the operand. If he sticks to the basics... to add strings together everything must be a string... then he will always get it right without any confusion.

Comment: I understand. The downside is the OP goes away with a faulty/incomplete understanding of how AppleScript works. AS is rather complicated, unfortunately. Perhaps it'd be better to supply a solution to their specific problem, along with some links to further learning material which they can read in their own time, e.g. the [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide), which describes the language's features, or [an AS book](http://www.amazon.com/s/?url=field-keywords=applescript), which also teaches how to use it.

Comment: I disagree when you say "faulty/incomplete understanding". What you showed him was how to code improperly. If you're adding strings then your objects should be strings. That's the correct way and that's what I demonstrated. Applescript only steps in and performs the coercions when your code is faulty. Most times applescript is predictable in how it tries to fix things as you showed. But let's not confuse things here, it's bad programming if applescript has to fix your code.

Comment: "What you showed him was how to code improperly." - Nonsense; you're presenting personal dogma as if it were hard fact (see also: cargo cult programming). AppleScript has a weak, dynamic type system by design (i.e. variables are untyped, operators may coerce their operands as needed). The ASLG is the definitive reference on AppleScript behavior (E&OE) and quite clear on how `&` and other operators are [_designed_](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/reference/ASLR_operators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH5g-SW2) to operate.